# Site Attributes

Tags: discussion, design, private-beta, promotion

Alright, so it [looks](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/so-where-do-we-discuss-vote-on-the-sites-name-url-style-etc/103#103) [like](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-is-the-faq-going-to-get-written) it's up to us to figure out the site attributes and a way to vote on them.

I think having a single post that will link to the others will help with the organization, so here it is:

- [Domain](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/site-attributes-domain-name) ([How will the domain be chosen?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/how-will-the-domain-be-chosen))
- [Logo & Style](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/site-logo-proposals)
- [FAQ](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-should-our-faq-contain) ([How will the FAQ be written?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-is-the-faq-going-to-get-written))
- [Moderators](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations)
- [404 image](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/404-image-nominations)
- [CAPTCHA image](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299/captcha-image-nominations)
- [How do we promote our site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/how-do-we-promote-our-site)
- ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site's design has been long-established.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the site name and domain should be chosen separately. All of the existing Stack Exchange sites have them being the same, and not doing this for WebApps would be confusing.

Comment: Who says the final name has to be "Web Applications" or "WebApps"?

Comment: It's just an easy way to refer to a site that hasn't got a name yet. I'm not suggesting that it will be called that.

Comment: @Roger Pate: It's a [working title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_title).

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that the site logo and style should be combined. After all - a purple logo will not blend well with an orange theme...

Comment: There. I merged them together.