# How will the domain be chosen?

Tags: discussion, private-beta, meta, domain-name

Things to consider are:

- Domain squatters
- It has to be relevant to the site name (e.g. "Web Apps" would make sense to have a webapps.com domain)
- Someone could easily register the most popular domain names we write down

See also: [What should our .com domain be?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be)

Comment: Anyone know how it was done previously with the 3 sites that exist?

Comment: SO: Votes on Coding Horror. SF: ??. SU: Jeff's choice.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted [by Jeff Atwood](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/banner-to-inform-users-of-domain-decision-process/231#231):

> We will have Robert monitor the domain
>   suggestion question and pre-emptively
>   register any suggested domains that we
>   like and think have a real shot. At
>   the end of the domain suggestion
>   process, we'll donate the suggested
>   names back to the community.
>
> (that's basically how we did it for
>   Stack Overflow, anyway...)

Answer (score 2):

Choose a domain before it enters public beta.

A requirement would be to have a [banner to inform users of the decision process](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/banner-to-inform-users-of-domain-decision-process).

**Update:** this idea was [rejected by Jeff](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/banner-to-inform-users-of-domain-decision-process/231#231).

Comment: I updated my answer -- Robert will monitor the name suggestion question and pre-emptively register anything likely.

Answer (score 0):

Leave a section of the site only accessible to members that were in the private beta so they can decide on a domain

Answer (score 0):

Write a post on the Stack Overflow blog asking people to suggest domains privately and setup a poll question here before the private beta ends to decide which one (or just to decide finalists, then buy them and setup a public poll).