# Accepted answer not showing at the top?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Accepted answers don't seem to be displaying at the top of the answer list on here (as in meta). Is that by design or is it a bug?

One example is [this question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/how-will-the-domain-be-chosen) where [eagle's posting of Jeff's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/how-will-the-domain-be-chosen/237#237) has been accepted, but still appears at the bottom with no up votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self-accepts do not sort to top, but stay in the default sort order.

Comment: Ahah, makes sense :)