# Site Logo / Style Proposals

Tags: discussion, design, public-beta

Please post as answers below, your proposals for a logo and color scheme for WebApps.

**Note:** you must have a copy of the logo in a vector format. However, you may post a PNG or JPG below as a preview.

**Also:** as noted in the comment: **Original artwork ONLY!**

[Vote on other site attributes](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/site-attributes)

Comment: Original art only please....

Comment: Why don't you go with the same approach as the other websites (using a submission process with a cash reward at the end)? It seemed to work quite well and not cost too much.

Comment: Everyone knows we should have the Facebook [Like] button as our logo ;-)

Answer (score 15):

In the hope that this name proposal wins  ([SVG version](https://web.archive.org/web/20130602142352/http://dl.126sn.de/clicklogout.svg)):
[image: clicklogout]
<sub>(source: [126sn.de](http://dl.126sn.de/clicklogout.png))</sub>

Variant suggested by akira  ([SVG version](https://web.archive.org/web/20130602133244/http://dl.126sn.de/clicklogout2.svg)):
[image: clicklogout]
<sub>(source: [126sn.de](http://dl.126sn.de/clicklogout2.png))</sub>

Comment: i like it. i would put the poweroff thing over one of the 'o's ...

Comment: I like this, as it retains the somewhat familiar looks of the current site logos. I'm not sure whether I'm too big a fan of the orange/red though.

Comment: Those colors are nice.

Comment: I like the first one, with the power button in front of the text.

Comment: This would probably look better with different colors. I'm not a fan of the orange/red either.

Comment: It doesn't look like that this name proposal catches up again, it is not worth it to create a new color scheme for this. Maybe I'll creating another logo soon...

Answer (score 13):

Here's my take:

I like Neo's logo of an ON switch. However that logo has been used on several sites, including one of the Stackexchange 1.0 sites [onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com). But I like the icon itself a lot so I worked around it. To me the idea of Web Apps is that they reside in the cloud. And for our site's purpose(Q&A, Discussions) I think it's fitting to add a cloud speech bubble concept.

P.S. I believe we're going with the [Domain name](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be) "NothingToInstall.com"

[image]

For the actual implementation on the site, it will be more polished. Please see my [design concept post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/design-ideas-for-web-applications-site-updated-with-screenshots).

[image]

Comment: Very nice logo :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my set:

[image]

(available in [SVG format](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/webapps.svg) as well)

Comment: Is that a modified version of Google Gears?

Comment: I don't know... I've never used Google Gears. I made this from scratch.

Comment: This is well done but *very* similar to the Stack Apps logo.

Comment: @Robert: It's not supposed to be... any ideas for changes are welcome!

Comment: Maybe if I change the colors?

Comment: There. I changed the colors. Feedback is welcome - the original colors are still available in the linked SVG file, which I will update later.

Comment: I like this one. The middle looks a little like gears, but it's a quite generic shape so I guess it's not a big deal.

Comment: This looks a lot like the logo the API site is using.

Comment: @neil: You mean [StackApps](http://stackapps.com)? Ya, it's not supposed to be, but you're the second person to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the design of the beta site.  The logo should be updated to match the final domain name of course, but I think the current color scheme is excellent.

Comment: Jeff said that this design is reserved for beta sites only. We can't vote to keep this design.

Answer (score -1):

A combination of the other two:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Here is another:

[image]

Comment: the russian half moon? :)

Comment: Well, a lot of webapps use a star to represent 'a favorite something'.

Comment: I like the idea of using a star in the design, but this really looks like a Russian thing (not that there's anything bad with that, just doesn't suit the theme of the website).

Comment: What about this same idea but with the two shades of blue in George Edison's other design?