# Please have a rectangular search box

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, search

Compare

[image: square box] with [image: rounded box]

The first one is from [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) and the second one is from [nothingtoinstall.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), when using Google Chrome.

The second one looks really ugly and unprofessional to me. Please stick with the normal rectangular search box. I think it won't even hurt the site design theme.

Comment: btw, why does this get a -2?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to disable the outline on focus for the search and add interesting/ignored tags. I do agree having a rectangular outline out a curved input box looks weird. Fix is on the way!

Answer (score 0):

How about just [disabling it](http://beckelman.net/post/2008/09/15/Override-Chromes-Automatic-Border-Around-Active-Fields-Using-CSS.aspx) for the search box instead?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken maybe Jin was attempting a portion of the apple spotlight search field and missed out on fixing the focus as follows.

[image]
http://www.apple.com/

During public beta design was discussed already.
[Design Ideas for Web Applications Site (updated with screenshots)](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/design-ideas-for-web-applications-site-updated-with-screenshots)

and again on announcement out of public beta and design requests here
[New Design Launched](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/new-design-launched)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Google Chrome (Version 6.0.472.63). See my result:
[image: Screenshot]

**Note:** I changed the picture. See now.

Comment: Where is your on hover focus ? I do not see it

Comment: I have removed the outline on focus for webkit.

Comment: @phwd I changed the picture. See now.