# Moderator nominations

Tags: discussion, moderators, public-beta

Should we be selecting moderators for the site?

Given Jeff's answer I hereby open up this question for moderator nominations.

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- The top voted nominations can go forward to the vote.
- The voting will be done on a separate question.

Some guidelines (from [Jeff's original answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations/276#276)):

1. Must be a currently registered user in good standing
2. Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
3. Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
4. Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
5. They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

[Vote on other site attributes](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/site-attributes)

Comment: I reckon that is important even during the beta stage as it can help guide the site in the right direction, or at least prevent it from going the wrong way. Although i note the diamond mods are hanging around, maybe they are all that is needed for now.

Comment: I do miss my regular mod rights for editing posts...

Comment: Should each nomination be a different line?

Comment: @Noctrine - See the update

Comment: good topic, ChrisF. @Ivo Flipse: :)

Comment: I wonder if someone is going to propose Jon Skeet.

Comment: You want to be a mod yourself @ChrisF? I'm getting tired of having to follow up on your mod flags ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - someone would have to nominate me ;)

Comment: Done: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations/295#295

Comment: Perhaps Jeff's guidelines could be added to the OP so that one doesn't have to be searched through the page to find them?

Comment: Isn't it about time this goes to a vote?

Comment: @Al Everett, I think the plan is to have a vote - complete with new nominations - after the site leaves beta. Robert Cartaino will be the person to ask.

Answer (score 16):

I nominate [Ivo Flipse](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/17/ivo-flipse).

Comment: Only if they give me a StackApp to monitor the moderator pages of multiple sites in one place

Comment: You can use Red Bull for that.

Comment: or just jedi-tricks. can't be that hard.

Answer (score 15):

I nominate [Senseful](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/207).

Comment: Sure, I'll accept the nomination, thanks

Comment: @Senseful: No, **thank you!**

Answer (score 9):

I (Kinopiko) think [phwd](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/40/phwd) is a good user who matches Jeff's criteria (I don't know if he wants to do it, so the last one, number 5, I'm not sure of).

Comment: @Kinopiko - see my updates to the question. They can accept the nomination by commenting or editing the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I nominate [ChrisF](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/21/chrisf). And I double nominate him for Super User, so I can waste more time here!

Comment: I accept the nomination.

Comment: on SU as well? :)

Comment: @akira - I wouldn't be so presumptive & anyway the point is moot - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/summer-2010-moderator-appointments

Comment: Well it was worth to try! Guess I have to email the team more often...

Comment: Agh, I thought this was the permanent mod nomination page, not the pro tem suggestion page. Sorry 'bout that bump.

Answer (score 5):

Can you self nominate?

If so: I nominate TomatoSandwich.

: timezone: GMT+10!

: carefactor for webapps.stackexchange: 10/10!

: time able to be given to system: ALL OF MY TIME! (outside life duties)

: sanity: VARIABLE!

: sex: FEMALE

: why: I use a lot of social media applications, and have a good understanding of how these bad boys work, given my background in IT. Also, I've been coding web (apps) pages since I was 11, so given I have been doing this stuff over half my life, how could you not pick me!
(Also, I totally have published work on a specific web app (oracle apex), so I must be doing something right)

Comment: How can you be able to give all your time to moderation?

Comment: Because I have no life! (I do have a 9-5 job, but because of my timezone shift, it'll look like I'm moderating all the time, because I sleep when you are not looking at the site.. or something)

Comment: so you are essentially deleting posts while their owners are at sleep? :)

Comment: I am the illegal migrant, locked in the StackExchange machine over the American night, ne'er to leave til the work is done. I am the ghost in the shell.

Comment: Fair suck of the sav mate, i'll give you a vote on that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, discussion about which community members would make good moderators is definitely appropriate!

Some guidelines:

1. Must be a currently registered user in good standing
2. Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
3. Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
4. Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
5. They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

Comment: In what timespan are Moderator Elections to be expected? Will there be any temporary moderators (like Ivo) assigned until then?

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't sure if self-nomination was kosher, but after speaking to a couple people about it, my opinion has been changed.  So...

[rchern](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/416/rchern)

I missed out on the private beta by just a few minutes, but I was ready for the public beta!  I have been very active since the public beta started, and my rep shows that.  As for Jeff's other criteria, I'll let my activity speak for itself I suppose.

Comment: +1 For sounding like a nice guy on chat. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I nominate [Al Everett](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-everett).

Comment: I'd be happy to.

Answer (score 1):

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/971/mike-the-mike I'm up for the job if we are in fact allowed to nominate ourselves...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that we also consider what timezone each mod is in, as it is important to be covered around the clock. This is especially relevant in the early stages of the site as there are no 10K users able to help out.

Comment: In the early stages, they're 2K users.

Comment: yes, that is a "please give us scaling problems" problem. at the moment it is only important to have SOMEONE.