# Targeted answer in URL hash fades to white not transparent

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When you use an answer link the answer in question is highlighted briefly when you visit the link. The highlighting fades to white for the current sites. For example, try this link: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user/7935#7935) or this one on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926.

On Web Apps, unfortunately, because the background color is grayish, the white background after the color animation now makes the answer stand out. Try: [Moderator nominations](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations/282#282) or [How do I delete my Facebook account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-delete-my-facebook-account/22#22)

It's not *very* obvious, but it's definitely visible, and definitely a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed as this behaviour no longer occurs.

Note: Using Chrome Dev Tools the background is now set to transparent