# 404 Image nominations

Tags: discussion, design, private-beta

Post your nominations for final 404 image here.

- Quote the source as well as posting the image so the team can negotiate rights if necessary.

[Vote on other site attributes](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/site-attributes)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site design has long-since been settled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I nominate a [highly-voted image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites/27121#27121) from the meta question (was found by George Stocker). Google is a web application, right?

[image: Image at imgur.com.]

It's from the blog post "[Star Wars Droids](http://www.monkey-and-banana.com/1136-star-wars-droids)" (blog "Monkey and Banana - LOL Blog.
The blog for refreshing humor"), although I'm not sure whether you could use it, given that it has a trademark in it.

Comment: yeah, this would be a good fit for a web apps site