# "You've been logged in" message hidden behind "Welcome to" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I just came to nothingtoinstall.com without being logged in and the "Welcome to..." banner appeared as expected. But then the white "You've been logged in" banner appeared below that, with the link just barely visible. I'm guessing some CSS was missing or something...?

EDIT: here is a screenshot as taken by Kyle Cronin on [this answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/new-design-launched/611#611).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.