# Make more contrast between visited and unvisited links in linked and related questions section.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If you take a look at the entries in the related questions list on [any question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/new-design-launched) it is REALLY hard to tell which you've visited and which you haven't (the colors are #666666 vs #888888). [stackoverflow is a little better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c), but I'll probably bring up the issue there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Fix is on the way.