# Find and replace of NothingToInstall not quite right?

Tags: bug, status-completed

In this question: [New Design Launched](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/new-design-launched)

and here too: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/public-beta-period-has-officially-expired-so-what-now

The links have `.com` at the end, which looks (to me) like a global find and replace gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I replaced all instances of `.com.com` with `.com`