# CAPTCHA image nominations

Tags: discussion, design, captcha

Post your suggestions for the final CAPTCHA image here.

- Quote the source as well as posting the image so the team can negotiate rights if necessary.
- I suppose it should be a robot themed image.

[Vote on other site attributes](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/site-attributes)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site design has long-since been settled.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a brain the size of a planet, and I am forced to do menial tasks like verifying humans.

How degrading.

[image]

Source: Wikipedia article on Marvin the Robot.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Found on this post: [The Church of Google](http://mouthygirl.com/2009/08/17/the-church-of-google/)

Answer (score 0):

Colossus from the Forbin Project, but this:

[image]

and this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [theage.com.au](http://blogs.theage.com.au/schembri/colossus.jpg))</sub>

Are the only two half-way decent images I've been able to find.