# What conferences and events could WebApps.SE have a presence at?

Tags: discussion, promotion

In order to continue to grow the site, we need to work on promoting the site.  It isn't something that is just going to happen, we need to be proactive about this.  There are several ways to do this, [please see this question which needs your input](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/how-do-we-promote-our-site)!

Robert recently posted on the blog:  [A recipe to promote your site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/).  I like his suggestion of narrowing the focus.  So, in the answers to this question, let's identify some top events or conferences that WebApps.SE could have a presence at.

<sub>If you have any ideas about new events, please post that as a separate question.</sub>

For each answer, please identify the following:

> **Name**
>
> **Dates**
>
> **Location**
>
> **Brief Summary**
>
> **Ways we can be involved** (if you have ideas such as:  be a sponsor, have a booth, etc)

Answer (score 2):

**Name** : South by Southwest - http://sxsw.com/

**Dates** : March 11-15 2001

**Location** : Austin,Texas

**Brief Summary** : SXSW® Interactive features five days of compelling presentations from the brightest minds in emerging technology, scores of exciting networking events hosted by industry leaders, the incredible new SXSW Trade Show and an unbeatable lineup of special programs showcasing the best new digital works, video games and innovative ideas the international community has to offer

**Ways we can be involved** : Maybe walk around the festival with the webapps logo (nothingtoinstall) Jin did, people are bound to ask. Also if Jeff and Spolsky allow some sort of [Exhibition Booth](http://sxsw.com/business_at_sxsw/exhibitions) for all SE sites