# What experts/evangelists are there in the Web Applications area that we can reach out to for promotion?

Tags: discussion, public-beta, promotion

In order to continue to grow the site, we need to work on promoting the site.  It isn't something that is just going to happen, we need to be proactive about this.  There are several ways to do this, [please see this question which needs your input](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/how-do-we-promote-our-site)!

Robert recently posted on the blog:  [A recipe to promote your site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/).  I like his suggestion of narrowing the focus.  So, in the answers to this question, let's identify experts in the field that we can reach out to.  People that can help us get word out about the site, draw users in, and perhaps even have a presence here.  We can worry about how to get in touch with these people later, but we need to come up with the *who* first.

Comment: Probably some tech blogs, like DownloadSquad are always useful if they want to plug an excellent post

Answer (score 1):

John Gruber - Technology blogger.

Site: http://daringfireball.net/

He does not really have a specific webapp speciality but he blogs alot about technology (specifically apple). alot. I would suggest we get everything in order before going to him though. From reading his reviews on products/people he is very honest with his opinion.

Oh and yea, original creator of **Markdown**

Answer (score 0):

This might not appeal to everyone, but a mention from [Scoble](http://scobleizer.com/) could go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Brett Kelly - Technology blogger.

Site: http://nerdgap.com

Brett writes about technology, including webapps such as Dropbox, Evernote, and Foursquare. He's now an employ of Evernote, but maintains his blog separately from that company.