# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, private-beta

We need to come up with "**things *specific* to webapps that need to be mentioned in the faq**. [...] [The] most relevant thing to focus on is that topmost section of the [faq]." <sup>[[Jeff Attwood]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-should-our-faq-contain/277#277)</sup>

If you look at [Super User's FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq), you will notice that it lists things that are on topic and things that are off topic.

Here's an example of the template we might use:

> {site-name} is for expert and advanced users of web applications. If you have a question about …
>
> - {on-topic-examples}
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - {off-topic-examples}

Please submit suggestions for things to be listed in the `{on-topic-examples}` and `{off-topic-examples}` sections above.

**Vote up based on whether or not you agree with the example.**
For example, if someone writes "This site *is not* about computer software" and you **agree**, **vote it up** (not down), since "is not" was used. Conversely, if someone wrote "this site *is* about computer software" and you **don't agree** with it, then you should **vote it down**.

Please follow these guidelines:

- Enter a single bullet you would like to see in the FAQ per answer. This will help the voting process.
- Specify if your suggestion is on-topic or off-topic.
- This isn't the same as the Area 51 on-topic/off-topic questions. It should be more like what you see in the [SuperUser.com FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) (e.g. "This site is not about **videogames or consoles**").

[Vote on other site attributes](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/site-attributes)

See Also: [How is the FAQ page going to get written?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-is-the-faq-page-going-to-get-written)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here - there already is an FAQ here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq that seems to cover it all pretty well.

Comment: @scunliffe: I don't understand it fully either yet... I'm still waiting for a clarification from Robert. See the other page, [How is the FAQ page going to get written?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-is-the-faq-page-going-to-get-written), for the discussion so far.

Comment: Since this is CW, it shouldn't require 30 different answers when it's about trying to fix up the FAQ.

Comment: Should each site FAQ also link to a factored-out common FAQ on the stackexchange platform?  "You may ask yourself, how do I work this?"

Answer (score 10):

{off-topic-example}

This site is not about developing web applications.

Answer (score 10):

{off-topic-example}

Questions about web applications with adult content are not allowed.

See [Jeff's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-allowed/367#367) to [this question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-allowed)

Answer (score 7):

{on-topic-example}

This site is about **using** web applications

Comment: While I completely agree with this, many of the current questions are "recommend me a web app for x" or "is there a good alternative for x". I think this is something that need clarifying as I can't help but feel that the current direction of the site puts it towards becoming "This site is about recommending and using web applications"

Comment: As was discussed here (http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54/should-rec-tags-be-added) the recommendation posts are not encouraged, but tolerated as long as they are not too popular. In that case, I think we should not mention that this site is about recommending web applications (although, maybe we could put a note about recommendations).

Answer (score 4):

{off-topic-example}

This site is not about scripts (e.g. Wordpress.org, phpbb, etc.)

Comment: Good point, although we should specify that questions about hosted wordpress ([...].wordpress.com) are valid.

Answer (score 3):

{on-topic-example}

This site is about **bookmarklets**.

Answer (score 3):

{off-topic-example}

This site is not about managing self-hosted web applications (wordpress.org) although if you have a [...].wordpress.com account, ask away.

Comment: Might need some rewording :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a way to word it because I don't have a firm opinion on it.  That said, however the community decides to handle (CW / closed for off-topic, etc?) "List of " questions should be explicitly stated in the FAQ.

Comment: I think this should be a global stackexchange FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

{off-topic-example}

This site is not about **computer software**.

Comment: well, except that we use the inverse of that definition on SU and people argue with us that "websites are software too man!"

Comment: Although it is valid to ask for software which helps using web apps.

Answer (score 2):

{on-topic-example}

This site is about **"is there a webapp that..." type of questions**.

*See [this thread](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic) for the discussion, and [my (Ben Gartner's) answer here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic/427#427).*

Answer (score 1):

{on-topic example}

Questions about browsers are on-topic as long as they are related to the usage of a web application (Greasemonkey, other plugins and extensions, Google Chrome's application shortcut feature, etc.)

[Discussion about it here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/are-questions-about-browsers-accepted-as-long-as-they-are-related-to-using-a-web)

Answer (score 1):

{policies}

- It is **OK** to answer a question by providing a non web-based solution as long as the user did not specify that the solution had to be web-based.

[Discussion that spawned this suggestion here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-it-accepted-to-answer-questions-with-non-web-based-solutions)

Comment: You're correct, though I wouldn't want every answer to be: use this desktop tool it's much more powerful

Answer (score 1):

I propose a new section in the FAQ called **policies** which give best practices about using the website (how to answer, comment, etc.). It is related to the on/off-topic discussion, but relates to other things than just questions.

Alternative section name:

- **best practices**

Mark your suggestions as **{policies}** for now (until we settle on a name).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we could add a link to the ["Define 'web application'" question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/define-web-application) and settle down on an answer ([here's my proposal](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/define-web-application/279#279)). That way users will better know about which websites they can ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

{off-topic-example}

This site is **not** about **"is there a webapp that..." type of questions**.

*See [this thread](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic) for the discussion, and [my (Will M's) answer here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic/429#429).*

Answer (score 0):

{off-topic example}

This site is **not about browsers** and their features (plugins, extensions, etc.).

Answers that require the use of a particular extension or browser feature **are encouraged**.

See discussion about this in [this thread](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/are-questions-about-browsers-accepted-as-long-as-they-are-related-to-using-a-web).