# Are questions about "adult" web apps on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, support, faq-proposed, scope

Would it be appropriate to have questions about adult-themed apps that potentially could contain links to such 18+ sites (in answers or questions)? Just asking 8]

[Return to what should our FAQ contain](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-should-our-faq-contain)

Comment: On a side-note: most adult sites use very advanced techniques, so aside from their content they are quite interesting from a technical point of view ^^

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, I don't think we want this, as it would cause us to get globally banned from web filtering software.

**So including adult links, or even mentioning adult sites by name, is explicitly not allowed**.

Comment: I completely forgot about that aspect - deleting my answer.

Comment: Does this include links to potentially explicit search results (in discussions of search filtering software, and false positives)? I'm not sure if I'm even allowed to discuss image filtering software if this restriction is in place.

Comment: I don't think that might happen on a major scale. Wikipedia seems to be going fine without censorship: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:What_Wikipedia_is_not#Wikipedia_is_not_censored