# Questions about Adult apps that conform to Jeff's restrictions allowed?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, scope

Will suggestions about adult web apps that do not contain a site name or url/link be allowed?  This would not violate Jeff's restrictions from this question:

[Previous Question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-on-or-off-topic)

Comment: How can you ask a question about something without mentioning its name?

Comment: What's with all these adult app questions cropping up?

Comment: I think discussing how to handle questions about adult apps is valid. Adult websites are a very, very significant part of the internet whether you like it or not. If we want to build a Q&A site about web applications, we need to have a clear position on this.

Comment: Jeroen answered pretty well - just seeking clarification about what you can ask.  Let's face it, a lot of innovation comes from the adult world and Jeff's points are valid - so where is the line that we should stay behind?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be merged with the previous one ? It would be easier to follow the discussion about it.

Answer (score 6):

Our [Content Policy](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) reads:

**Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

Comment: That's...  Not an answer.  One can only count it as an answer if one assumes that as long as it doesn't violate this (which is established in the Content Policy, which everything is subject to) as well as what [Jeff laid out previously](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/367/15278) is ok.  Is that indeed the case?

Answer (score 3):

If there is any “Adult” related items on the website, or for that matter just a few words that are often used on “Adult” website a lot of company’s web filters will block the site.

I wish “Web applications” to be useable by people at work, therefore it must not having **anything** on it that could give **any person** a reason to think it should be blocked.