# Is asking "is there a webapp for x" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

These questions struck me as way off topic from the home page, but perhaps the question really was intended to be "is there a web app for this."  Is this type of question considered on topic?

[How can I convert 1930s dollars to today's (cost of living adjustment)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/how-can-i-convert-1930s-dollars-to-todays-cost-of-living-adjustment)

[What services are available for sending money to family overseas?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/what-services-are-available-for-sending-money-to-family-overseas)

Comment: I modified both Ben Gartner's answer and your answer in the other thread. I think it's better to have the discussion in a separate thread (i.e. this one) than in the FAQ one.

Comment: See Also: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-some-sites-or-lets-make-a-list-of-x-type-questions

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, such questions are off topic.  This site should be about how to make advanced use of webapps.  I don't think the purpose of this site is (or should be) to provide an index to what's out there on the internet in the way of webapps.  Just finding one for a particular purpose should be the function of google or some other method of indexing the web.

(Posting this to promote discussion of the point, since the other answers went the other way.  And because this is what I actually think.)

Answer (score 5):

Not a fan of these since they're very close to "help me remember something" and "do my decision making for me" type of questions.

Better versions of these would be if the user was already trying something in an app and leaving an aside that if it's not possible in their current web app of choice, feel free to suggest an alternative.

You then get the benefit of having the question focussed to a web app at hand and a side bonus of another out there that could overtake its use.

In the end they still read as "pitch me an idea that I should go with since I am non-committal about my choices in life".

Note that the [Help/On Topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page now explicitly says that web app recommendations are off-topic.

> Please note that the following subjects are considered **off-topic** here:
>
> [...]
>
> - Web application recommendation requests