# Mystified by post closing

Tags: discussion

I don't understand why [webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18392](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18392) was closed.  The canned explanation given ("We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion") makes no sense to me, because I don't see how the post deviates from the expectations the explanation describes.  How could the post be reworded to be acceptable?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

I think this could also be "too localized" -- I'm not clear how that question would ever help anyone else. It's specific, which is good, but a bit *too* specific.

The question also doesn't demonstrate any research or provide any examples; did *you* look for this and what did you find? Share your research with us!

As Random (aka 8 days) pointed out, it's also generally more acceptable to ask about power usage of particular webapps here rather than where to find them. Sure, the web is a big place, but help us map it in your question!

Thanks for asking about it here on meta.

Answer (score 1):

As the first person to vote to close on that question, it was because it's one of those "help me look for something that matches this list of requirements".

Thoughts of the same but with different words have been given on these type of questions in, "[Is asking "is there a webapp for x" on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic/908#908)"

A better version of that would be for you to already be using a web app and trying to get it to work how you want it to. And as an aside, mention or comment that if something else does it better, that answer would be acceptable.

That version would help people using the app as well as allowing room for alternatives. The current version is rather cloudy.

Comment: It is unfair to close a post not for what it says, but for what you *choose* to read into it.  That post did not say "help me look" or anything remotely like it.  That's the reading that *you arbitrarily choose to impose on it*, in disregard to what it actually says.  The post *specifically* asked "does anyone know" of a webapp that does something.  I also note that the answer that has by far the most votes to the question in the post you linked says that this sort of question makes sense for this site.

Comment: That's one reason for a close vote given. But "help me look" does read the same as "does anyone know" since they're both asking for something to fill in a hole. @kjo

Comment: No: "help me look" = "Google it for me; work for me".  In contrast, "tell me, *if you already know*" requires no extra work from the responder (above and beyond the work required to answer any other question sent to the Web Applications).  By the way, how is asking *any other question* in this site *not* asking for "something to fill in a hole"???

Comment: This post doesn't address one of the OP's points: closing a question with a nonsensical canned reason is rude. why does this happen?