# Why was my question just closed

Tags: discussion

I raised a question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19374/smart-survey-tools-which-present-weighted-answers-to-the-user and it was closed shortly after with no real explanation. It was a genuine question. If it was in the wrong place then please tell me where it should be don't just close it.

Comment: Eight Days of Malaise closed my question

Comment: bottom line, "share your research", as it says on the ask question page in the sidebar.

Answer (score 5):

One common thing to do when looking for a tool suggestion is to list the tools that you've already reviewed and explain *why* they are not adequate.  This may attract responses from people experienced with the tools you've already reviewed and who may have advice on how the tools may do what you desire.  It may also attract people willing to share knowledge of tools encompassing more of your feature list.

Comment: right on -- "share your research". It's science!

Comment: Interesting, thanks! What if even hours of research lead to zero results? Is it OK to say "I searched but did not find", or should I refrain from asking the question altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Your question reels off a list of features you would like a web app to have. And that someone should find this for you.

That's not constructive and is essentially, ["do my search/research for me".](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/is-asking-is-there-a-webapp-for-x-on-topic/908#908)

A better version of that question would be to actually already use a web app and come here asking how you go about doing something and needing guidance. And if people have another web app they could recommend instead, they would.

And now you have two concrete solutions where you first had an open slather of "who knows what, let's see what we have here, maybe, no, next, something else".