# Is it accepted to answer recommendation questions with non web-based solutions?

Tags: discussion, scope, answers

I'm referring to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/good-free-wireframing-apps) where one of the solution is a non web-based app. Do we want that or should we only answer with web-based solutions even if there are better apps out there?

Comment: The referred question is was closed as off-topic in Feb 2015 because of the change in the Web Applications scope, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering with non web-based solutions is **OK** because the point is to help the user and there might not be good web-based apps.

Comment: Assuming the OP did not ask in the requirements for it to be a web app (`on desktop or online`) I agree. If the OP specifically asks for something that is online so that he does not have to go through installing on every computer he uses then no.

Comment: @phwd makes sense

Comment: it's not only about the OP.. somebody who Google's the question expects to find a webapp on this site :)

Comment: Stupid Froyo autosuggestion changed googled > Google's :)

Comment: If you suggest a desktop app, you should probably explain why you are suggesting a desktop app and why it is better than a web app counterpart (if one exists).

Answer (score 1):

Often apps are hybrid anyway, for examples most photo sharing websites have an optional application (or active x control) to help with uploading and tagging lots of photos.

Comment: yes, but the website is standalone -- the app is *USELESS* without the website to support it.

Answer (score -1):

I think comment would be better, because desktop apps usually not running on all platforms and if somebody is looking for an answer in webapps, it should be a webapp.

Comment: I just reposted it here because of the duplicate..

Comment: The only restriction this site imposes is that *questions* must be about webapps. *Answers* with non-webapp solutions are perfectly fine in my opinion.

Comment: @eagle maybe you're right.. :) sometimes it's much easier to get the app..