# Can I answer with a desktop application?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it accepted to answer questions with non web-based solutions?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-it-accepted-to-answer-questions-with-non-web-based-solutions)

I know this site is about webapps, but for some questions, I have desktop app suggestions that the asker might use. Is it acceptable to respond with these answers, or should I make it a comment on the question instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think comment would be better, because desktop apps usually not running on all platforms and if somebody is looking for an answer in webapps, it should be a webapp.