# How does a faq-proposed post become part of the FAQ?

Tags: support, faq-proposed

How does are questions chosen to change from [faq-proposed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to [faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)?

There are some questions which I would like to suggest adding as official FAQ posts, but it seems that a few of these questions haven't been looked at in 7 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism you seek is: pick a suitable existing meta “thread”, post a ‘Q’ that requests that have the [faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag added, give your reasons why and tag it [discussion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) [faq-proposed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).

---

IMO none of the Qs so tagged here at present (maybe 17 of them) merit the tag, with two possible exceptions.

One of the exceptions is this question (IMO not merited), the other [How is the FAQ page going to get written?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-is-the-faq-page-going-to-get-written). That other is from before the time the site graduated and may be of historical interest but IMO no more than that (IMO better without tag [faq-request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-request)). For example it should not be possible to post additional answers to it, now or in the future.

It does add ambiguity however. Even contemporaneously there is a Comment (from [@Gelatin](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20/gelatin)):

> Are you talking about the FAQ page or questions tagged FAQ?

Judging by [Jeff’s A](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/314/60716) all what that was about was what can now be found [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) – ie “Asking”.
That page does mention a [community-curated FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) but as can be tested, clicking that link takes one off site.

The Usage guide for the tag is:

> Proposals for new entries for the FAQ repository on this site should use this tag.

That, and decisions about what is on topic and what not (for which we have [scope](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope)) are easily confused but quite different. For a start, the FAQ is a meta matter. We have a tag [faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) and its Usage guide is (at present):

> These questions are the most frequently asked and answered questions on Meta.

WAmeta does not have an [Asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page of is own and IMO does not need one. What is on topic for meta is straightforward: Web Applications Stack Exchange other than questions that belong on the WAmain site (everything else is off topic).

The [faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag is a ’pink tag’ – one of a dozen or so moderator-only ones. A post along the lines “please mods, add that pink tag to such and such a Q” (presumably along with some justification of why merited) could appropriately carry the [faq-request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-request). There are, for the moment, no such requests on WAmeta.

Asking a Q on meta where an A is sought and requesting that such a pair have the pink tag applied should be kept as separate posts.